# cancel a c++ 11 async task

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11

How can I stop/cancel an asynchronous task created with `std::async` and policy `std::launch::async`? In other words, I have started a task running on another thread, using future object. Is there a way to cancel or stop the running task?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short no.

Longer explanation: There is no safe way to cancel any threads in standard C++. This would require thread cancellation. This feature has been discussed many times during the C++11 standardisation and the general consensus is that there is no safe way to do so. To my knowledge there were three main considered ways to do thread cancellation in C++.

1. Abort the thread. This would be rather like an emergency stop. Unfortunately it would result in no stack unwinding or destructors called. The thread could have been in any state so possibly holding mutexes, having heap allocated data which would be leaked, etc. This was clearly never going to be considered for long since it would make the entire program undefined. If you want to do this yourself however just use `native_handle` to do it. It will however be non-portable.
2. Compulsory cancellation/interruption points. When a thread cancel is requested it internally sets some variable so that next time any of a predefined set of interruption points is called (such as sleep, wait, etc) it will throw some exception. This would cause the stack to unwind and cleanup can be done. Unfortunately this type of system makes it very difficult make any code exception safe since most multithreaded code can then suddenly throw. This is the model that `boost.thread` uses. It uses `disable_interruption` to work around some of the problems but it is still exceedingly difficult to get right for anything but the simplest of cases. `Boost.thread` uses this model but it has always been considered risky and understandably it was not accepted into the standard along with the rest.
3. Voluntary cancellation/interruption points. ultimately this boils down to checking some condition yourself when you want to and if appropriate exiting the thread yourself in a controlled fashion. I vaguely recall some talk about adding some library features to help with this but it was never agreed upon.

I would just use a variation of 3. If you are using lambdas for instance it would be quite easy to reference an atomic "cancel" variable which you can check from time to time.

Comment: cf. [baol's answer to 'Is there a way to cancel/detach a future in C++11?'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33315162/427158) for a code example of the 3rd way.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11 (I think) there is no standard way to cancel a thread. If you get std::thread::native_handle(), you can do something with it but that's not portable.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can do like this way by checking some condition:

```
class Timer{
public:
    Timer():timer_destory(false){}
    ~Timer(){
        timer_destory=true;
        for(auto result:async_result){
            result.get();
        }
    }
    int register_event(){
        async_result.push_back(
            std::async(std::launch::async,[](std::atomic<bool>& timer_destory){
                while(!timer_destory){
                //do something
                }
            },std::ref(timer_destory))
            );
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::future<int>> async_result;
    std::atomic<bool> timer_destory;
}
```