# How to finalize std::async

Tags: c++

Here is an example code:

```
struct T
{
    T()
    {
        task = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]()
        {
            while(work)
            {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }

    ~T()
    {
        work = false;
    }

    std::future<void> task;
    std::atomic_bool work;
};
```

Should I somehow finalize future in the destructor or the above code is ok ?

Comment: Are you asking if you need to explicitly wait on the future?

Comment: This might be helpful reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531096/can-i-use-stdasync-without-waiting-for-the-future-limitation

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is not okay, but not for the reason you may think. Since the shared state referred to by `task` was created by `std::async`, the d'tor of `std::future` will block when destroying `task`. But that still won't help you.

The problem is that members of a class are destroyed in reverse order to their initialization. Since `work` is initialized last, it will be destroyed *before* `task`. So even though you set it to `false`, your task may in fact be referring to a dead object when it runs the check in the loop. So you'll have undefined behavior on your hands.

You can solve it by moving `work` before `task`, so its lifetime is longer. Or you may explicitly call `task.wait()` in the destructor of `T`. Personally, I think the latter is clearer.