# Can broken promises be safely ignored?

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

Suppose I have a thread that is running a [`packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task).  I am not interested in the return value of the task and only wish for the thread to run the task silently in the background.  As such, I never use the [`get_future()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/get_future) to obtain any handle on the `promise` of the task.

My concern is, when the `packaged_task` is completed and the destructor [`~packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/%7Epackaged_task) is called, it states that

> As with std::promise::~promise, if the shared state is abandoned before it was made ready, an std::future_error exception is stored with the error code std::future_errc::broken_promise).

My question is, assuming I never get a handle on the `promise` via `get_future()`, can I safely ignore the `std::future_errc::broken_promise` exception?

My question is motivated by trying to modify [this thread pool library](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h) to ignore return values since I'm only using it with `void`-returning functions.  I was thinking to simply change the return type of the `enqueue` function to return void and remove the `get_future()` on [line 72](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h#L72).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531096/can-i-use-stdasync-without-waiting-for-the-future-limitation

Answer (score 1):

A `packaged_task` can only ever have a broken promise if you never actually call it. That is, if you don't invoke `operator()` at all (or the similar `make_ready_at_thread_exit`) before the `packaged_task` is destroyed. Calling the task *will* make the state ready (either with an exception or a "value", which can be `void`).

Comment: So once the `packaged_task` is called, I can safely destroy it regardless of whether or not  the `promise` was read or not?